# Can't load image with Glide/Fresco

Tags: android, image, android-glide, fresco

[This](http://lh3.ggpht.com/-_n5OKR4rD-E/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/BX-8krMucww/c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo/photo.jpg) image can't be loaded with Glide/Fresco. Just empty image. Why?

This is my code:

```
Glide.with(context)            
 .load(ValidationHelper.getValidImageUrl(elements[position].author!!.image)
 .into(viewHolder.avatarImage)
            //viewHolder.avatarImage.setImageURI(ValidationHelper.getValidImageUrl(elements[position].author!!.image))
```

Comment: Are you having this problem with a specific image? What is the value of `ValidationHelper.getValidImageUrl(elements[position].author!!.image` ?

Comment: I just checked here- Glide is able to load this url. You need to verify you have a working internet connection, your firewall is not blocking the url as it's blocked in some places (Google hosted images). Also as pa1.Shetty said- verify the value of ValidationHelper.getValidImageUrl(elements[position].author!!.image

Comment: `val imageUrl = ValidationHelper.getValidImageUrl(elements[position].author!!.image`. Now either print it out in your console or use the debugger to verify if the link is valid (and not null before unnecessarily calling Glide)

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code :

```
Glide.with(this)  // Activity context
   .load(ValidationHelper.getValidImageUrl(elements[position].author!!.image) // Set URL
   .resize(100,100) // If you want to Resize the image then set image size
   .placeholder(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_defuser)) // Default Image
   .error(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_defuser))
   .into(viewHolder.avatarImage); // Imageview
```